# Generating primary key based on maximum value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have database tables `TableA` and `TableA_Stage` with same columns and I want to copy the records in `TableA_Stage` to `TableA` generating primary key based on maximum value in `TableA`.

I tried this sql and it didn't work because same primary key value gets inserted :

```
insert into tableA(col_pk, col1, col2)
  select (
          select max(col_pk)+1 
            from tableA
          ),
         col1, col2
   from tableA_Stage
```

I am looking for sql statement to copy records

Comment: Maybe you should just set autoincrement on the table and use `intert into tableA (col1, col2) select col1, col2 from tableA_Stage`?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798766/how-to-create-an-oracle-sequence-starting-with-max-value-from-a-table

Comment: @schlenk, the link you provided creates a sequence object. I want to copy without creating a new sequence object.

Comment: Are you aware that this won't work in a multi-user environment? And it's definitely not scalable because it will get slower the bigger TableA gets.

Comment: Have you tried `select (select max(a.id) from a) + rownum, ... from table2`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The performance of this will be fine if there's an index on the col_pk of table_a and it's constrained to not null. It just needs a coalesce or nvl to ensure that an empty table_a does not cause a nul col_pk to be generated.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: that doesn't make it correct in a multi-user environment though

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Agreed -- but if no multiuser environment, this works fine for tasks like loading reporting tables and whatnot. I used it for a data warehouse very successfully -- very particular circumstances of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is that what you want to achieve. But it is not good idea to do so.

```
insert into tableA
(col_pk, col1, col2)
select (select max(col_pk) from tableA) + col_pk,
       col1, col2
from tableA_Stage
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should generate your keys as:

```
select
  Coalesce((select max(col_pk) from tablea),0) + rownum
  col2,
  ...
```

Comment: The generated Ids should follow/continue the primary key values in main table.

Comment: Which is the main table?

Comment: tableA is the main table.

Comment: The code selects the maximum current value from table, using 0 if the table is empty, and adds 1 onto it for every row inserted. This technique is fine as long as you only have one process ever inserting into that table, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the difference between the maximum PK value in `tableA` and the minimum PK value in `tableA_Stage` and add that difference plus 1 to the PK value from `tableA_Stage`. You're simply adding 1 to the max PK value from `tableA`, which gives the same value for every single row. You probably want something like this:

```
insert into tableA(col_pk, col1, col2)
  select (
          (select max(col_pk) from tableA) - (select min(col_pk) from tableA_Stage) + 1 + col_pk
          ),
         col1, col2
   from tableA_Stage
```

Comment: @Griffey.thx for the reply. The generate PK should continue/follow the sequence in tableA for the new records inserted from tableA_stage. IF the tableA has PK sequence as 1, 2, 3...20501, the new PK value should be 20502 and so on.

Comment: @Jay, that's exactly what the statement I wrote should do.